# I have a txt file labelled private key, inside is what i assume to be base64 string ending with =

Tags: private-key, wallet-recovery

I have a txt file labelled private key, inside is what i assume to be base64 string ending with =, is there any way I can access the wallet I assume this is the private key for?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are in possession of an actual private key and not a random Base64 string, consider [this answer to convert it manually yourself](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95442/convert-base64-private-key-to-wif) or use an external program [like this](https://github.com/casascius/Bitcoin-Address-Utility) or [this](https://github.com/vsergeev/btckeygenie) to convert it to the Wallet Import Format (WIF).

It would be preferred if you do this in a virtual machine disconnected from the internet for security reasons.