# Help to recover BTC

Tags: wallet-recovery, bitcoin-wallet-app

In 2013 i purchased some BTC. From the guy that sold me i have recieved some text and password. The text has 76 signs. Starts with AAQ and has + sign. Also has upper and lower case letters and numbers and 12 charecters pass.The instructions that I remember were: go to bitcoinadress.org and there copy adress and key which have balance 0 then use pywallet to create wallet.dat file and insert it to bitcoin core wallet. But I cant rememer what to do with recieved text.I had instructions but deleted form HDD. Can somebody help me what I need to do.

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Base64 Private Key to WIF](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95442/convert-base64-private-key-to-wif). Alphanumeric text with '/' and '+' characters is usually [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a BIP38 encrypted Private Key, you cloud try:

1 - go to https://www.bitaddress.org/

2 - go to "Wallet Details"

3 - paste the text you have in "Enter Private Key"

4 - click on "View Details"

5 - paste your 12 characters pass in "Enter BIP38 Passphrase"

6 - click on "Decrypt BIP38"

If everything goes well, you should be able to see your Bitcoin Address and your Private Key Wif, then you will be able to import this private key in some wallet software and spend your bitcoins.

Comment: I thought [BIP38](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0038.mediawiki) was [Base58](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding#Base58_symbol_chart) encoded. Doesn't that mean that BIP38 keys should start with a "6" not with an "A", be 58 characters long not 76 and not include "+" signs?

Comment: yes it should be, but as he said he received those instructions, I think it is worth try to see if he can decrypt the text he has using that bitaddress procedure.