# Decoding a base64 wallet from 2014

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet-import-format

I have a Bitcoin wallet file (not called wallet.dat). That has a string that looks like this:

> FuXjd1EjroiAURK ... 5zYDsaaP/1FizzJo0IrkwEe6bmN7av0ww==

I omitted the middle part (...), it is **728 characters** long, and was **created in July 2014**. I don't remember what I used to create it.

I've tried this: [Convert Base64 Private Key to WIF](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95442/convert-base64-private-key-to-wif) (both answers), but didn't get an address with any transactions. The way I stored the file makes me believe that it was used.

Since it was from 2014, I don't think it is an HD wallet and most BIPs haven't been developed yet.

How can I decode this?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you've provided, it seems like you might be dealing with a backup from a Blockchain.info wallet (now Blockchain.com) from that time period. The length of your Base64 string is typical for blockchain wallets of that era because they can hold multiple keys and metadata.

In addition to Base64 encoding, it uses PBKDF2 and AES to encrypt the keys and metadata within. Should you have the password, the [official Blockchain Decryption tool](https://github.com/blockchain/my-wallet-backup-decryption-tool) can be used.